# Анимация и setContentView

Tags: android, java

```
    rocketImage.startAnimation(translate);
    setContentView(R.layout.rules)
```

Подскажите, как заставить выполнить `setContentView(R.layout.rules)` после окончания анимации?

Comment: @pissed, не забывайте принимать ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
translate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() { 
  public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) { 
  }

  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) { 
    setContentView(R.layout.rules);
  }

  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) { 
  } 
});
```

См.классы

- [`Animation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)
- [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)